# How to set price for an extension in Google Chrome Developer Dashboard?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

In past, there used to be an option to set price for your extension in Google Chrome developer dashboard. But recently I tried, I could not find such an option any where. I have looked in their new dashboard as well as the old one but couldn't find any such possibility.

Searching on internet did not indicate such a change. Official documentation also indicates that it should be as obvious as selecting a *price tier* in the dashboard. I am wondering if I am missing something very obvious and that's why don't see the pricing option. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The new dashboard is known to be a mess so switch to the old one.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried the old one as well. Couldn't see this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has disable the ability to publish paid extensions until further notice. You should of received an email to the account associated with your web store account a couple months ago.

Here is a news article also addressing it: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/01/27/google_disables_web_store/

Comment: But the original announcement says that the issue was resolved in March 2020.